# How to pivot a table and obtain the total with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame with Pandas and I want to transpose the dates into columns and sum the total of hours for each person.

```
# Current Pandas DF

| Full Name |    ID      |   Date     | Hours| 
 ----------- ------------ ----------    -----
|  John A   |   00001    | 2019-01-01 |  5.7 |
|  John A   |   00001    | 2019-01-02 |  NaN |
|  John A   |   00001    | 2019-01-03 |  6.0 |
|  John B   |   00002    | 2019-01-01 |  8.0 |
|  John B   |   00002    | 2019-01-02 |  3.5 |
|  John C   |   00003    | 2019-01-01 |  1.0 |
|  John C   |   00003    | 2019-01-02 |  1.0 |
|  John C   |   00003    | 2019-01-03 |  NaN |

# Desired result

| Full Name |    ID    | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-02 | 2019-01-03 | Total | 
 ----------- --------- ------------ ------------ ------------- -------
|  John A   |    00001 |    5.7     |     0.0    |    6.0     |  11.7 |
|  John B   |    00002 |    8.0     |     3.5    |    0.0     |  11.5 |  
|  John C   |    00003 |    1.0     |     1.0    |    0.0     |   2.0 |
```

I have cleaned the NaNs manually from the original dataset and replaced the values with 0 and I came up with the following code snippet:

```
pd.pivot_table(sheet_data_cleaned, values = sheet_data_cleaned.groupby('Full Name')[['Hours']].sum(), index=['Full Name'], columns = 'Date').reset_index()
```

The problem with my code is that it doesn't display the sum of total hours, besides, cleaning the NaNs manually isn't the best approach especially if you too many records.

I want to know how can I replace those NaNs in Pandas and get the desired Data Frame. Feel free to improve this question and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juts check with `crosstab` + `margins`

```
pd.crosstab(df['Full Name'],df.Date,df.Hours,margins=True,aggfunc='sum',margins_name='Total').drop('Total').fillna(0)
Out[628]: 
Date          2019-01-01    2019-01-02    2019-01-03   Total
Full Name                                                   
  John A              5.7           0.0           6.0   11.7
  John B              8.0           3.5           0.0   11.5
  John C              1.0           1.0           0.0    2.0
```

Comment: just missing a `fillna(0)` and it's perfect

Comment: How could you add an extra index? That is, `Full Name` and `Id`?

Comment: @abautista we can reset_index or set_index

Comment: So, what I need is to display `Full Name` | `ID` | `2019-01-01`  | `2019-01-02`  | `2019-01-03`  | `Total`. I tried to use modify your code to add `set_index=[df['Full Name'], df['ID']]` but it seems this is an unexpected keyword. Can you update your code, from the solution to implement this change, please?

Comment: @abautistaa where is the ID in your sample data

Comment: I have done the changes to my question and I have added the ID column.

Comment: @abautistaa pd.crosstab([df['Full Name'],df['ID']],df.Date,df.Hours,margins=True,aggfunc='sum',margins_name='Total').drop('Total').fillna(0)

Comment: I get this error `AssertionError: arrays and names must have the same length`

Comment: @abautista or just`s=pd.crosstab(df['Full Name'],df.Date,df.Hours,margins=True,aggfunc='sum',margins_name='Total').drop('Total').fillna(0);s['ID']=s.index.map(dict(zip(df['Fill Name'],df['ID']))'

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the following in two steps :

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Hours', index=['Full Name'],
             columns=['Date'], aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0).reset_index()
df2['Total'] = df2.apply(lambda row : sum([row[x] for x in df.Date.unique()]), axis = 1)
df2.columns = pd.Index(df2.columns, dtype='object', name=None)
df2
```

**Output**

```
+-------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
|       | Full Name  | 2019-01-01  | 2019-01-02  | 2019-01-03  | Total |
+-------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
|    0  | John A     |        5.7  |        0.0  |        6.0  |  11.7 |
|    1  | John B     |        8.0  |        3.5  |        0.0  |  11.5 |
|    2  | John C     |        1.0  |        1.0  |        0.0  |   2.0 |
+-------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
```

**EDIT**
To get rid of the index name in df2 (`Date`)